# how to read the array of data in html templates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have three variables and i was created one array and pushed all these three variables in to this array.

And in my html template i am using a table. I tried with *ngFor but it is not working and also i tried with string interpolation and that too not woriking.

I am getting an error called <--can not read property "title" of undefined-->

In my console i am getting data like this....

```js
array of data
(3)[{...}{...}{...}]
0:{key:"-LtZprPfMtDgzuxmaI5o"}
1:{price:1}
2:{title:"title1"}

array of data
(3)[{...}{...}{...}]
0:{key:"-LtcY8_6dd8fzibK9EYV"}
1:{price:2}
2:{title:"title2"}

array of data
(3)[{...}{...}{...}]
0:{key:"-LtcZF9NHknDZ0OcKzHg"}
1:{price:3}
2:{title:"title3"}
```

And here my product.component.ts

```js
import { ProductsService } from './../../products.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireAction, DatabaseSnapshot } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent{
  constructor(
    private products:ProductsService,
    private db : AngularFireDatabase
    ) { 
    products.getAll().on('child_added',function(c){
        let data = c.val();
        let key = c.key;
        let price = data.price;
        let title = data.title;
        let array=[];
        array.push({"key":key});
        array.push({"title":title});
        array.push({"price":price});
        console.log('array of data',array);
    })    
  }
}
```

And my admin-products.component.html

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let p of array">
        <td>{{p.title}}</td>
        <td>{{p.price}}</td>
        <td ><a [routerLink]="['/admin/products',p.key]">Edit</a></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how did u use ngfor?

Comment: @PeterHaddad: I was updated my code

Comment: Why do you use an array here. Just create an object with properties

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra: I want to use the object properties into html template to render data in to a table

Comment: You have print log like this **console.log(array)** and you should use this for html 
**<div *ngFor="data of array">
<span>{{data.title}}</span>
</div>**

Comment: first of all, your `array` is a local variable inside the function. Secondly, when you change that, your going to face `this`-issue. Use fat arrow syntax instead of `function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your html code, I think you need a array of object.
for example :

```
array = [
    {key: 'key1', title: 'title 1', price: 10, },
    {key: 'key2', title: 'title 2', price: 10, },
    {key: 'key3', title: 'title 3', price: 10, }
]
```

if my assumption is correct then there are several problems here.

1. array construction is not ok.
2. your array variable is local. make it a public variable otherwise from html you can't access it.
3. In html, you are trying to iterate the array and each iteration, the data will be assigned in your local variable `'p'` (as you are using `*ngFor="let p of array"`)

so, change your code to this

```
import { ProductsService } from './../../products.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireAction, DatabaseSnapshot } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent{
  array: any = [];
  constructor(
    private products:ProductsService,
    private db : AngularFireDatabase
    ) { 
    products.getAll().on('child_added',function(c){
        let data = c.val();
        let key = c.key;
        let price = data.price;
        let title = data.title;
        this.array.push({"key":key, "title":title, "price":price });
        console.log('array of data', this.array);
    })    
  }
}
```

and change your html to this,

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let p of array">
        <td>{{p.title}}</td>
        <td>{{p.price}}</td>
        <td ><a [routerLink]="['/admin/products',p.key]">Edit</a></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Getting an error called can not read property 'array' of null

Comment: use this.array instead

Comment: @SrinivasNeelamraju please mark as accepted if it is exactly what you were expected or your issue is solved. Upvote it if it at least helps you to solve the issue. you can do both if it is accepted to you. If it is irrelevant downvote it. Your feedback is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

- Have the loop in `tr` instead of `td`
- Change {{array.title}} to {{p.title}}
- Make `array` global

.html

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of array">
        <td>{{p.title}}</td>
        <td>{{p.price}}</td>
        <td ><a [routerLink]="['/admin/products',p.key]">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

.ts

```
export class AdminProductsComponent{
     array:any[] = [];
     products.getAll().on('child_added',function(c){
            let data = c.val();
            let key = c.key;
            let price = data.price;
            let title = data.title;
            this.array=[];
            this.array.push({"key":key});
            this.array.push({"title":title});
            this.array.push({"price":price});
            console.log('array of data',this.array);
        })  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    <tbody *ngFor="let p of array">
        <td>{{array.title}}</td>
        <td>{{array.price}}</td>
```

into this:

```
    <tbody *ngFor="let p of array">
        <td>{{p.title}}</td>
        <td>{{p.price}}</td>
```

You have an array of object, therefore you need to use `ngFor` to iterate inside the array and then use the variable `p` to access the attribute's values.

Answer (score 0):

`array` is a local variable inside your callback. Make it a member of your component to make it available in the template.

```
export class AdminProductsComponent{
  array: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private products:ProductsService,
    private db : AngularFireDatabase
    ) { 
    products.getAll().on('child_added', c => {
        let data = c.val();
        let key = c.key;
        let price = data.price;
        let title = data.title;
        // you probably want one item per product, not three??
        this.array.push({ key, title, price });
    })
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<tbody >
  <tr *ngFor="let p of array">
    <td>{{p.title}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Getting an error called can not read property 'array' of null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @SrinivasNeelamraju fixed. Use an arrow function instead,

Answer (score 0):

Define an array property in your component and pass objects into it.
Use Arrow function for the on callback so your this context is the component.

```js
import { ProductsService } from './../../products.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireAction, DatabaseSnapshot } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent{
  // Define property here
  public array = [],

  constructor(
    private products:ProductsService,
    private db : AngularFireDatabase
    ) { 
    products.getAll().on('child_added',(c) => {
        let data = c.val();
        let key = c.key;
        let price = data.price;
        let title = data.title;
        this.array.push({key, title, price});
    })    
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting an error called can not read property 'array' of null